# Creating JobConf in Eclipse for hadoop

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, libraries

I am a .Net developer (with not much experience) and learning `Hadoop` now. However my preference is to strike `Hive`, I just wanted to touch java code and get familiar with Eclipse first.

I was trying to write `Driver` code to run and `Map Reduce` job. But when I tried to create `JobConf` object I am getting syntax error.

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(MaxTemperature.class);
```

As a developer I can guess it is a issue with some missing libraries. But really not sure where should get those libraries from. Can anyone help me please?? Treat me as a beginner and I am really uncomfortable with eclipse for now. I can't even find a solution explorer (of Visual Studio) in eclipse. Please help.

**Edit**

If I run into similar problem tomorrow, please also try guiding me to get missing libraries specially for Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest grabbing an [eclipse tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html) or watch a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft0oD_F6-ac).

In Eclipse, every line with a red scribble has an icon on the left which displays the error message. Clicking on it will pop up some suggested fixes to the problem.

The shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + O` automatically adds missing import statements. In case the class `JobConf` is not found, you should first add `hadoop-core-x.jar` to the classpath of your project.

If in doubt you can find missing JARs using http://www.findjar.com. Just type in the missing class and it will suggest some JARs.